# Facing problem to add vuex data into firestore

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vuex

I'm creating a e-commerce with Vue & Firebase. Trying to add some cart information from the current logged in user. Strange thing is at the very first time information saved perfectly. When I trying to add some again. That dosent work and show this error.

"Uncaught FirebaseError: Function DocumentReference.set() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined"

So I have to refresh that page. Then it work again. I cant understand where is the problem.

Note: If I try to add any other value instead of cart. then it works fine.

```
    checkout(){
        var db = firebase.firestore();           
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;

        db.collection("orders").add({
            user_id:user.uid,
            cart:this.cart                    
        })

        console.log(this.cart);    

        this.$store.commit('emptyCart')                   
        this.$router.push({ name: 'Home'})                
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `this.cart` is not undefined??

Comment: yes. at the very first time the value of this.cart added perfectly. after that when I try to add again. that time it not works.and shows the error.

Comment: What do you get the second time if you put the console.log (console.log(this.cart);) before db.collection(.....

Comment: And what do you exactly mean by "I try to add again". You should add the entire code to your question.

Comment: actually when I checkout the cart then cart became empty. if I try again add some item on the cart and checkout 2nd time. then this error appear.